# useEffect React Hook rendering multiple times with async await (submit button)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect

I am trying to basically disable the submit button so my api calls only get triggered once/ someone can't click on submit again while the operation is already underway.

I converted the runOnSubmit function to an async function and call it directly.  I have based this off many other solutions and basically when I do this and debug I can tell that isSubmitting is still set to true and the hook gets called multiple times/ the submitAsync function is called twice.

Basically, the setSubmitting gets called, but doesn't actually do anything until there is another refresh.  I want it to only ever get called one time.  I have no idea why submitAsync would even run multiple times since the dependencies (errors) are not changing.  If they were changing then noErrors would be different the second time and it wouldn't even hit that block.

```
useEffect(() => {

        if (isSubmitting) {
            const noErrors = Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
            if (noErrors) {

                const submitAsync = async () => {
                    await runOnSubmit()
                    setSubmitting(false)
                }

                // clear out touched upon submission
                setTouched([]);
                submitAsync();
            } else {
                setSubmitting(false);
            }
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [errors]);
```

Update- adding in more information:

```
 // function for form submission
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const validationErrors = validate(values);
        setErrors(validationErrors);
        setSubmitting(true);
    }
```

Since this function sets Submitting to true it should rerun the useEffect function since isSubmitting is in dependency array.

Button calling submit and disabling it:

```
<Button 
 disabled={isSubmitting} 
 buttonType="submit" 
 text="Create Account" />
```

My Button component:

```
<button 
  type={props.buttonType}
  disabled={props.disabled}
  onClick={props.onClick}>
     {props.text}
 </button>
```

SECOND EDIT- adding in console.logs:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("use effect running", isSubmitting)
        if (isSubmitting) {
            console.log("use effect submitting true")
            const noErrors = Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
            if (noErrors) {
                console.log("use effect no errors")
                const submitAsync = async () => {
                    console.log("inside submit async")
                    await runOnSubmit()
                    console.log("after function")
                    setSubmitting(false)
                    console.log("after set false")
                }

                // clear out touched upon submission
                setTouched([]);
                submitAsync();
                console.log("console after submit")
            } else {
                setSubmitting(false);
            }
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [isSubmitting === true]);
```

When running:

```
use effect running true
use effect submitting true
use effect no errors
inside submit async
the user called signup method
console after submit
after function
after set false
use effect running false
```

Issue here which doesn't make much sense is that "console after submit" runs before "after function".  It's as if the async await isn't doing anything.

Comment: Seems that code provided is not enough to reproduce your issue. `[errors]` as second argument to `useEffect` hook  may cause it to stale and not rerun until `errors` object is changed. But it depends on how you declared and modify `errors`. Or `useEffect` may be called after each render and it will mostly depend on how `isSubmitting` is changed

Comment: I actually think you are right and not sure why I am even using errors there.  What I changed the dependency array to is `[isSubmitting === true]` since I want it to rerun only when submitted.  The problem is I can continuously click submit and it's not disabling.  Adding in handleSubmit function and submit button above

Comment: I put your code in codesandbox and cannot reproduce your issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-called-twice-0ybcy

Comment: That's so odd.  I would try to put the full code, but it is using all our backend api's so is hard to replicate.  I added in the console.logs though and it's clear that it isn't awaiting the response.  Maybe I need to try to use promises instead, but i've already tried .then().catch() and so difference

Comment: @StephenPhillips if we can't see where `errors` is coming from and how it is declared and modified then it's going to be difficult-to-impossible to help solve your problem. It's also not clear why `isSubmitting` is not in your dependency array since you reference it in the callback body.

Comment: @JaredSmith please see second edit piece where isSubmitting was added to dependency array and errors was removed.  What I have realized based off Fyodor code sandbox is that if I wrap my runOnSubmit() in a timeout then I solve the problem, although I think using a timeout is not a solution I should be using and need to dive into actually why runOnSubmit is not waiting before moving on

Comment: So basically the error was that the function I was awaiting needed to have async await down the whole function chain.  I had about 3 layers deep and the lowest layer wasn't using async await.  The other piece is that when you call the function it doesn't wait till it's done before calling functions after since that isn't in an async function, so basically the ```console.log("console after submit")``` runs right away.  Most of the issue is related to my understanding of Auth0 and how they handle promises

Answer (score 2):

TO ANY NEW PERON HAVING THIS PROBLEM:

This second array argument passed to `useEffect` with data could be causing the multiple render. Pass in only an array `[]` and it will render once.

As stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)
by react official site. The effect can be stopped if certain changes have not occurred between re-renders. This will prevent it from rendering multiple times